# knockout css binding within foreach based on user input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have a table like below. the user is supposed to type the address info into the third column. If it's empty, then I added a styling

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
      <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
           <td><input type="text" style="width:100%"  data-bind="css:{warningStyle: address.length == 0 }, value: address"/></td>

          </tr>                                   
 </tbody>
```

To test it, Here's my code about `people` in js

```
people = ko.observableArray([{id:'1', name:'a1', address:'aaa'},{id:'2', name:'a2', address:''}])
```

When I first load the page, it works as supposed. the 1st person has no styling applied and the 2nd person has the styling (because the address is empty).

Now it I type some address for the 2nd person, it still has the css style applied. My question is why? Shouldn't it has the css style removed becasue the address is not empty anymore? How do I fix this?

Comment: The address property isn't an observable, try : {id:'1', name:'a1', address: ko.observable('aaa')}

Comment: And also use `address().length` instead of `address.length`, (with `()`) if you make it observable.

Comment: Thanks Marius and Ivan. Now it works. I thought making it an observable array would make everything inside an observable. clearly that's wrong. How do I accept your comment as an answer?

Comment: It is impossible :) You can only mark it as "useful to the post".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happened because address property is not observable. You can fix it using [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin or without it in next way

```
var data = [{id:'1', name:'a1', address:'aaa'},{id:'2', name:'a2', address:''}];

function Item(id, name, address) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.address = ko.observable(address);
}

//do some basic mapping (without mapping plugin)
var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
    return new Item(item.id, item.name, item.address);
});

ko.applyBindings(mappedData);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f2Z72/)**